# How to mix named and unnamed string formatting

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting

How to mix named and unnamed string formatting?
Consider following not-running example:

```
s = "{:s}_{later}_{:s}".format("foo", "bar")
s1 = s.format(later="later")
```

I want to first format somthing including a `named` postioner for later formatting. How to archieve something in `python`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to escape the named formatting part:

```
>>> "{:s}_{{later}}_{:s}".format("foo", "bar")
'foo_{later}_bar'
>>> _.format(later="later")
'foo_later_bar'
```

Or the other way around:

```
>>> "{{:s}}_{later}_{{:s}}".format(later="later")
'{:s}_later_{:s}'
>>> _.format("foo", "bar")
'foo_later_bar'
```